# SQLSRV with Linked Server

Tags: php, sql-server

My issues basically revolves around me needing/preferring to use PHP's sqlsrv to access a sql-server 2000 database.  I've worked on the project already using that with a sql server 2005 to run all the queries through and switching to something like the ODBC PHP drivers would be a pretty big headache right now.  So now I have the original SQL Server 2000 database and 2005 installed on the same computer and I've created a linked server between the 2.  Testing it out in Management Studio Express worked by running a simple query to one of the tables.

Now, I'm using the exact same query in PHP using sqlsrv_query and running into an error.  My PHP code to test this out looks like this

```
$connectionOptions = array("UID"=>"user","PWD"=>"password"); 
$res = sqlsrv_connect("(local)\SQLExpress", $connectionOptions);
if(!$res) die("ERRORS : " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));    
echo "SELECT * FROM [ServerName].DB.dbo.Table<br/>";
$res = sqlsrv_query($res,"SELECT * FROM [ServerName].DB.dbo.Table");

if($res===false){
    die("ERRORS : " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
}else{
        var_dump($res);
    $ary = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res);
} 

var_dump($ary);

echo "<hr>";
var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());
```

The problem with this code is that the result of of sqlsrv_query doesn't return false but returns resource(11) of type unknown.  So running fetch_array on that result tells me that an invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_fetch_array.  I'm not sure what to do at this point.  Is there just a problem running a query on a linked server through sqlsrv?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with PHP, but a glance at the schema of the table might help to show any unusual fields that might be causing problems....wondering if there is a field type that isn't making it back from the DB to your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out the problem.  In my haste to make some code to test out whether or not the linked server worked, I just used the same variable name for the result of sqlsrv_connect and sqlsrv_query.  Turns out, that was the whole problem.  I switched the variable names so that the connection object is $Link and the query stays as $res.  Now, I get the access to the database that I was trying to get through 2005 into 2000.  So in the future, I definitely will name my variables a bit more carefully so I don't bang my head against the wall for hours.

Answer (score 0):

seems no error in your code.

Please try the fetch_array in a loop and update the result.

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo($row['field_name']);
}
```

also remove `var_dump($ary);`

Usually even if there is any error in the data display using '$row', the error message will show problem with 'sqlsrv_fetch_array'.